# Black screen, spinning wheel at launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've encountered a huge problem, some of my users have a strange crash. At the launch of my application, before or just after the launch screen, they get a black screen with a spinning wheel. After that the device is locked, and the app closed.

Nothing have change except Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3.

On my phone everything works fine, and on simulator as well. I can't reproduce it, and I've no crash on fabrics.

[image]

If someone have an idea about it please answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That spinning wheel is know as activity indicator. Again try to run your project. if phone and simulator is Ok then where you got this black screen? Please provide details.

Comment: It looks like your app not just crashes - it restarts the phone...

Comment: Clearly the app is crashing due to some reason. The activity indicator might be your own. Check your crashlytics for any frequent crashes.

Comment: @MaxPevsner Yeah but i'm trying to found why and how solve it

Comment: Try running your app using Xcode Instruments and check for high memory load and memory leaks. Simulator tends to have a lot of RAM but users on older iPhones may be having issues

Comment: @Makaille when you run the app on your device, do you run the DEBUG build or RELEASE?

Comment: As you mentioned your fabrics does not have a crash. The other issue can be that your app is going out of memory. Try looking for OOM issues on fabric. There is an option to check that on fabric.

Comment: @jarora You'r right, i've some OOM in fabrics. Now i'll try to solve it :) There is no way to track it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These might be OOM (out of memory issues). There is no way to determine what caused OOM as far as I know.

Try focusing on whether you have such issues on launch:

1. Database operations (bringing lots of objects in memory)
2. Raw image operations
3. Any infinite loops or operations that happen repeatedly.

Comment: Thank's, an image was in 1000px * 7000px.

Comment: I just had this happen for an iOS simulator in Xcode and it was indeed a memory issue. After I killed an app that was using too much memory using Activity Monitor it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Any image size is big or if we use any animated huge size image, application will get into out of memory.

I faced same issue in my application. Just removed the image or resize the image application will work normally.